# Powershell Studio OwnerDraw Control

Tags: forms, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-studio

I'm creating a form in Powershell studio but I'm can't get it to look the way I want. The Highlighting on objects once they've been checked or selected is anoying. I've heard I can Use the OwnerDraw control to modify this but the only code for this i can find is in C# and I can't convert it.
 [image: Example of Highlighting]

I need help with this or just making it so it 'un-highlights' it after say 1 second? I've used the Timer control before so could have it un highlight some how but I can't even find code examples for this either. I'd very much appreciate any help If people understand my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$checkedlistbox1.SelectedItem = $null
with a timed reset. Sorted. Thank you anyway all that read!